# JNLP w/ jdk1.7.0_51; Application Blocked by Security Settings

Tags: java

I'm attempting to upgrade an existing JNLP application from Java 1.6.0_45 to Java 1.7.0_51. I've run into many snags, all of them related to the new enhanced Oracle security.

It's my understanding that in order to run an application over our local network, developed by our local developers, we need our application JARs signed by a trusted CA.

Here's what I've done so far:

- Created a trusted CA using openssl
- Created a certificate and signed the certificate using the Root CA's key
- Imported the root certificate and signed cert into the keystore and used the keystore with jarsigner to sign all of the client JARs, including the application JAR with the JNLP files located in JNLP-INF/APPLICATION.JNLP
- Loaded the Root CA's cert and signed cert into %JAVA_HOME\jre\lib\security\cacerts
- Verified using jarsigner that all of the application JARs are properly signed and there are no errors (for example, it knows about the trusted chain of certificates or whatever it's called)
- Marked the application JAR and JNLP file with "Permissions: all-permissions"
- Cranked the security settings in the Java Control Panel down to "medium"
- Cleared the temporary internet files in the Java Control Panel
- Added an exception to the "Exception Site List"

Now I get this:

[image: a generic Application Blocked by Security Settings dialog].

I've tried executing the app using **javaws -verbose** and the JNLP file, but it doesn't display anything at all. I have logging turned up to the maximum in the Java Control Panel.

At this point, I'm out of ideas as to why this application won't run. As I said before, we're running this machine on the company intranet; we really don't care about authenticating the source of the JARs. We **do** need the application to run outside the sandbox.

If there's any way to get web start to spit out anything at all that might be useful, I'm all ears.

Comment: Have you followed the instuctions in the [JWS guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/index.html) on setting up [tracing and logging](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/jcp/tracing_logging.html)? There are several ways to go about it. Getting the java console to show would really help, as many of the error dialog messages are red herrings, while the console output usually gives much clearer feedback on the actual problems.

Comment: Also, I thought this is probably better suited for [so], with a tag for `java-web-start` or `jnlp`. Or possibly Super User if it's only config related, but I suppose the deployment options play are at fault.

Answer (score 2):

Check your codebase parameter.

The codebase parameter of the jnlp file must be the same as de codebase parameter of the manifest.mf file of the jars resources referenced by the jnlp file.

example:

file.jnlp

```
<jnlp codebase="https://myserver/mydirectory"
...
<resources>
...
        <jar href="https://myserver/mydirectory/myJar.jar" main="true"/>
...
```

manifest.mf of the myJar.jar

```
Codebase: https://myserver/mydirectory
```

Comment: This fixed my problem where I was getting the same dialog. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider this FAQ:

http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/signed_code.xml

TL;DR?  They've changed the security model for running Java in certain environments.

In my organization we had to make an adjustment in IE security settings.